# Access control in style from code

Tags: wpf, styles, code-behind, controltemplate

If I have a style that defines a control template, and in this I have a control, let's say a button, is there any way to access the button from code behind of the styled control?

Thank you guys! =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you have a style defined as follows

```
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="myTemplatedButton" Content="my templated button"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And you apply it to a button

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="my default button"  Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
```

You can access the button in the control template as follows

```
var myTemplatedButton = myButton.Template.LoadContent() as Button;
```

If the button is placed in a container inside the `ControlTemplate`, for example a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="myTemplatedButton" Content="my templated button"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can extract the main container and use [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method to get your templated button

```
var templatedControl = myButton.Template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
var templatedButton = templatedControl.FindName("myTemplatedButton") as Button;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work when that code is in the Generic.xaml file in the Themes folder.

Comment: @OmriBtian, LoadContent() create a new instance of object, when using 'Style' as 'ControlTemplate', use:
'myButton.Template.FindName("myTemplatedButton", myButton) as Button'.