# Templated FrameworkElement impossible to modify from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind, frameworkelement

## Context

I have a Style redefining the ControlTemplate applied on a FrameworkElement.
On given events, I want to be able to modify some properties of the content of the ControlTemplate (from code behind, not binding).

I get wanted FrameworkElement with this piece of code that I found here: [Access control in style from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208964/access-control-in-style-from-code)

```
FrameworkElement myTemplatedButton = this.Template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
Ellipse ellipse = myTemplatedButton.FindName("SliderButton_ButtonControl") as Ellipse;
```

This seems to find the element I'm looking for as I dont get any error and the reference is well set.

## Problem

However, when I try to update Properties like this

```
ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
ellipse.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Nothing changes in my application, and if I put a breakpoint in the code before re-triggering the event, I can see that the Property Visibility (for example) has been reset to Visibility.Visible.

It's like if the application was overriding my changes as soon as the function returns, and I have no idea why.

Comment: `LoadContent()` creates new elements based on the template. What particular element are you trying to change the appearance of?

Comment: Well its hard to say precisely without posting a big chunk of code, but if it creates a new instance, that explains why my modifications make no change to the program whatsoever. Do you have any idea how I could get the actual "SliderButton_ButtonControl" that has been defined in the style applied to `myTemplatedButton`?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadContent()` creates *new* elements based on the template.

If you want to modify an existing element, you should call the `FindName` method of the template of this one:

```
Ellipse ellipse = myTemplatedButton.Template
    .FindName("SliderButton_ButtonControl", myTemplatedButton) as Ellipse;
```

Comment: I find no such thing as "Template" in FrameworkElement

Comment: I thought `myTemplatedButton` was a `Button`. Isn't it? Cast it to `Control` or `Button`. Only controls have templates so this should be safe.

Comment: `((Control)myTemplatedButton).Template.FindName(...)`

Comment: I tried this and realized that my LoadContent()  on first line does not return the Button but the main Grid of the Style itself, using `Ellipse ellipse = this.Template.FindName("SliderButton_ButtonControl", this) as Ellipse;` fixed it, thanks!